# GRASS calculation of centroids : very important differences with QGIS calculation

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I use v.extract module in a python script :
    grass.run_command('v.extract', input=UH, output=centroids, type='centroid',
                                  overwrite='True', stdout = DEVNULL, stderr =      DEVNULL)

when I compare the result with result from calculation with QGIS I notice some differences.
[image]

red : GRASS v.extract, blue : QGIS.
One of my colleague observed the same with its own shapefile.
SAGA module (Polygon centroids) gives same result as QGIS. 
It seems that v.extract calculation isn't correct.

[image]

Comment: I also tried v.centroids which returns same result as v.extract. I'm going to test v.centerpoint but I'd really like to know why there is so much differences between all the results.

Comment: Thanks, _italic_v.centerpoint_italic_ is giving an acceptable result. But I've only found it for GRASS 7. There's programs using GRASS 6 that can't be upgraded to GRASS 7. It seems there is no solutions for these.

Comment: Please define "It seems that v.extract calculation isn't correct." - what do you mean?

Comment: I added another screenshot to my question where we can see that red crosses are centroids calculated with v.centroids and blue crosses with v.centerpoint (polygons are derivated from raster and  special process and they are very "irregular"). Blue crosses are more "central", better corresponding to what we expect  (for modelisation aims). I'd really like to know why the results are so different.

Comment: So, you want to have the centroid in the barycenter? This is not a condition of putting centroids: think of a "banana" shape - the barycenter may be outside of the banana but a GIS style centroid must remain inside. Hence not necessarily the same thing. [or I still don't get your problem]

Comment: The problem is that all the modules (GRASS-_v.centroid_, QGIS, SAGA-_Polygon centroids_) declare calculation of centroid and they give either centroid or barycenter.

Comment: As mentioned, centroid != barycenter (see my last comment above for an example). If you need the barycenters you need to use the right algorithm for that (see answer below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try v.centerpoint https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/addons/v.centerpoint.html with the default value `acenter=mean`. v.extract and v.centroid are probably creating points which are more like point-on-surface, not accurate but guaranteed to be within the polygon, see comments in https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/1654.